Waterproofing Garage Door Help

I have a garage that has an asphalt floor, unfortunately. The doorway doesn't have a threshold so water has been entering the space. The asphalt is pretty deteriorated so adding a rubber seal strip wouldn't adhere well.
The only idea I can think of is cutting a 6" strip out of the asphalt, pouring in concrete, and anchoring a 2x6. Is this reasonable? How deep should I go? I'm located in Ontario, Canada.
I'm open to any other suggestions.
Thanks!

Is there any possibility of installing a trench drain? That would let you redirect the water to a Better Place, at least until it freezes.

How does the ground slope?  Down into the garage?  Flat?  I'm guessing that it doesn't slope down from there.

@HABO I did consider this, but I think it might be more work in the long run to dig out another trench to redirect the water.

@mdfst13 there's a slight angle into the garage, so definitely not helping the situation

There is no way to effectively seal an ordinary garage door against continual hydrostatic pressure, i.e., standing water. Instead, try to eliminate the standing water.
Landscape so water is directed away from the door.

Repair the asphalt. Break up and remove loose stuff, then add repair mix, sloping away.
Add a threshold, which should adhere to the repaired drive.
Slope grass and soil on sides of door, digging away towards the street.
Move or extend rain gutters to direct water away from the door, below the bottom.


Thanks DrMoishe, that sounds like a good idea. I'll give that a shot!
